# WPF - Printing Array property in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, gridview

I have a List of this class:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public B[] B_details { get; set; } 
    public int phone { get; set; }

}
```

which I want to show in GridView.
Class B also have some properties, with property Name among them.
My grid definition is:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True" AlternationCount="2" />
</Grid>
```

The problem is, because it is AutoGenerated GridView - the values in the B_details column are all show up in the form "B[] Array".
How can I show the Names of all the B members of this class?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

1) Use a class instead of `B[]`, and override its `ToString()` method.  So you'd have something like:

```
public class BArray : List<B>
{
    public override void ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(Items.Select(item => item.Name), ", ");
    }
}
```

That way a comma-separated list of `B.Name` will get printed in the DataGrid column.

2) Turn off the auto-generated columns, and specify a `DataTemplate` for the `B_details` column.  Eg:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- insert other columns -->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B Details">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding B_details}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Well, I don't really want to change A class, this is why I'm trying to find 'out-of-the-box' solutions to this problem. Still, your second option seems proper to me, **except** from the fact that I still want to keep it 'Auto-Genaerated'. I still can think of a solution - but I need to know - is there is any way to transfer all those 'DataTemplate' tags into C#? Because if the answer is **YES** - I'm done. I just need to know how... Thankx!

Comment: @user2406262 There's `XamlReader`, which lets you create a DataTemplate in C# from a XAML string.

Comment: @user2406262 one other option: runtime typing and `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.  This gets slightly involved, but it useful for customizing what gets constructed by the DataGrid column generator.  You can essentially wrap a class like `A` in another type, and alter its runtime type including its properties, their values, etc.